# PM2 doesn't launch my nodejs app after server restart

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, reset, pm2

I have a vm instance set up in Google Compute Engine. I installed pm2, ran these commands:
`sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin pm2 startup -u zgintasz`

`pm2 start index.js`

When I type `pm2 list`, I then see my app process running.

I wanted to make sure my nodejs app relaunches when server is restarted, so I clicked `Reset` on Google Developer Console, typed in `pm2 list` again and I don't see it running anymore. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been in the same boat. After some searching I found that you need to 'save' after starting apps. 'pm2 save' - which dumps the processes.

This solved this issue for me personally, on my Ubuntu machine, but on my debian vps, it seems to still not persist as it should.

Answer (score 2):

use "pm2 startup"

- do not add sudo

Answer (score 1):

You can configure pm2 in server startup (`/etc/init.d/`) folder by typing command:

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH:path_to_bin pm2 startup os_name -u user_name
```

By doing so you are telling server to start your pm2 process on server start. But in order to do so, you need to store state of your pm2 process, which you can do by:

```
pm2 save
```

after configuring your pm2 in upstart.

So whenever your machine goes down and you restart it, pm2 will run the state of your node process from the point you saved it.